# Is there a way to create Google Maps KML layer in high resolution for retina display?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, google-maps-mobile

So I try to use KML Layer with custom icons for my Google Maps V3 mobile webapp (using jQuery Mobile). The base layer of the map is displayed correctly with sharp resolution and the zoom control is styled in compact mode automatically by the API, so I guess the API has detected the mobile device alright.

However, the custom icons on the KmlLayer appear to be blurry, as a common symptom of displaying low-res marker image on high density mobile display (retina and such), despite the fact that I've already used the double-sized images. I tried to adjust the `<scale>` tag in the kml file to no avail, since it seems to only affect the icons *after* being downsampled to 32*32 by Google's server.

So the question is: **is there a way to request the Google KmlLayer server to serve high-res tile images?** I didn't see any such option in the documentation. Maybe some trick on the KML generation side?

Thank you in advance.

UPDATE: as Chad stated below this is not currently supported. So while I open my photoshop and design the new marker image so that it won't be so much ugly when blurred out, here's the link for the [feature request on Google's page](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4925).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is "not currently". However you should post an issue about this and link it here. I'd gladly star (vote) for it: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?q=apitype%3Ajavascript3+kml

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I but I don't think it is available. All you can do is in your KML where you write

```
  <IconStyle id="mystyle">
  <Icon>
    <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
    <scale>1.0</scale>
  </Icon>
</IconStyle>
```

Make sure you use high resolution icon. I hope it helps.